# Override a builtin command with an alias

Tags: bash, function, shell, alias, built-in

I am trying to make an alias that overrides the `cd` command. This is going to execute a script before and after the "real" `cd`.

Here is what I have so far:

`alias cd="echo before; cd $1; echo after"`

This executes the `echo before` and `echo after command` however it *always* changes directory `~`

How would I fix this?

I also tried `cd(){ echo before; cd $1; echo after;  }` however it repetedly echos "before".

Comment: It doesn't _always_ change to directory. Try: `set /bin` and then your alias definition: `alias cd="echo before; cd $1; echo after"`and then `cd`. You'll see that you're not in your home but in `/bin`. Now, exercise for you: why? hint: what is `$1`? check your answer with `alias cd`: this will print what `cd` is aliased to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I also tried `cd(){ echo before; cd $1; echo after;  }` however it repetedly echos "before".

because it calls recursively the `cd` defined by you. To fix, use the `builtin` keyword like:

```
cd(){ pwd; builtin cd "$@"; pwd; }
```

*Ps: anyway, IMHO isn't the best idea redefining the shell builtins.*

Answer (score 10):

Just to add to @jm666's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28783618/6862601):

To override a non-builtin with a function, use `command`.  For example:

```
ls() { command ls -l; }
```

which is the equivalent of `alias ls='ls -l'`.

`command` works with builtins as well.  So, your `cd` could also be written as:

```
cd() { echo before; command cd "$1"; echo after; }
```

To bypass a function or an alias and run the original command or builtin, you can put a `\` at the beginning:

```
\ls # bypasses the function and executes /bin/ls directly
```

or use `command` itself:

```
command ls
```