# How to enhance a built in shell function while still using it

Tags: bash, function, shell, alias

Most of the times id like to not only just see where a specific command is but rather what it is.
An example `which lsd` tells me that this command is valid and existing in `/usr/local/bin/lsd`, but the more interesting info: Its a link to `../Cellar/lsd/0.16.0/bin/lsd` which tells me that its a command managed by homebrew.

So to see both, i wanted to create an alias. But alias seems to not play nice with arguments and even tho for simple commands that might work, i didnt get it to work with inline command execution e.g. `$(which $1)`.
Next i created a shell function to correctly use the command parameter:

```
function dings() {
  command=`which $1`
  echo $command
  eval "$command --version" # might not be supported by all commands
  ll $command
}
```

This function kinda does what i wanted it to:

[image]

except one thing: I have to remember the function name and to use it instead of `which`.
So i tried aliasing that function, but his is producing weird stuff since this results in calling itself recursively - so thats bad.
Since which is no command, i also cant use its exact location to omit this "bug".

**So the question is**: How can i replace the internal shell function `which` with my own function that still uses the default `which`?

And as an extra: How would i be able to display all found instances of the command in question?
So as in my case there where two versions of `lsd` in my system. First in path was the older brew version and second in path the `cargo` version.

**SOLUTION**:

```
function which() {
    IFS='
'
    set -f
    for LINE in `type -a $1`; do
        COMMAND=`echo $LINE | cut -d ' ' -f 3`
        if [[ $COMMAND = /* ]]; then
            version=`$COMMAND --version 2>/dev/null` # might not work with all commands
            [[ -n "$version" ]] && version="($version)"
            echo "$1 is $COMMAND $version"
            ll $COMMAND
        else
            echo $LINE
        fi
    done
}
```

[image]

Comment: `type -a foo` if using `bash` should be a start, where `foo` is the command/program  also  `which() { command which "$@"; }'` If you want to to override `which` executable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162680/10248678

Comment: You both should have posted that as an answer so i could accept, but thanks! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate solution to your question, "how can I select which `which` to use" is the builtin [`command`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-command) to suppress shell function lookup:

```sh
which() {
    command which "$1"
    "$1" --version
    ll "$(command which "$1")"
}
```

This also avoids the unnecessary `eval` and doesn't use a temporary variable. If you want to avoid running `which` twice, you can use a temp variable, but don't leak it to the environment:

```sh
which() {
    local whichpath
    whichpath=$(command which "$1")
    printf '%s\n' "$whichpath"
    "$1" --version
    ll "$whichpath"
}
```

But you can avoid using the external command `which` altogether and use the builtin [`type`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-type) instead:

```sh
type() {
    local typepath
    typepath=$(command type -p "$1")
    printf '%s\n' "$typepath"
    "$1" --version
    ll "$typepath"
}
```

Notice that this'll break if you use it to look up something that isn't an executable file.

Or, if you really want to confuse your future self, you could call the function `which`, but use `type` under the hood:

```sh
which() {
    local typepath
    typepath=$(type -p "$1")
    printf '%s\n' "$typepath"
    "$1" --version
    ll "$typepath"
}
```

---

Side note: this uses `ll`, an alias, which is usually disabled in non-interactive shells (such as when running a script); it is likely to be run in an interactive session where `ll` is defined, though. Just know that if you'd use it in a script, you'd better use `ls -l` instead of the `ll` alias.

Comment: Interesting, but id rather not confuse my future self! :)
How would i be able to list all matching command in my path, rather than just the first one?

Comment: @Andy There's `type -a` for that.

Comment: THX all - i really like the result!